# How to export the gui of an already running program to the remote computer via SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, xorg

I have pycharm on my desktop and I would like to access it from my laptop over ssh without having to close pycharm on the desktop (since I frequently have long tasks running).

Currently, I am able to start pycharm on my remote computer after ssh'ing into the host computer **only after exiting pycharm on the host**. I have to start it from the ssh command line, in other words.  That means I have to stop whatever processes are running on my host, close pycharm, and start it up again on the remote computer.

---

So...

If the gui application is already running on the host/server computer, how do I redirect the gui's output to the remote computer after logging in to ssh?

---